# I dont know how to send and integer by serial port from raspberry to arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi with an arduino mega via usb.
I did the connection and I can send an integer but only if i put the number by keyboard here is the code:

```
import serial
import time
arduino=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',baudrate=9600, timeout = 3.0)
arduino.close()
arduino.open()

var = raw_input("Introducir un Comando: ")
arduino.write(var)
```

It works

but if I want to send a varible integer like

var=1 it appears an error saying that the port is close, only making this change.
I tried using var =1, var ='1' var ="1" but nothing.

Can anyone help me? thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you are closing file just after open and before you try to write anything.

Comment: sorry was an errour copying.

Comment: if so, please edit your question so it shows actual code

Comment: yes i editted i put: arduino.close()
arduino.open()

Comment: you cant just pass an integer ... the only thing you can pass is bytes ... therefore the easiest is usually `var = "1"` you can send the byte 0x01 with `var = "\x01"` ... but it will print funny if you try and print it ... again its easiest to just send it as text ...

Comment: i dont know how do you say to use. I just tryed with the byte form but i get the same error. I want to send the same thing that i writed when i used raw_input but without use it because i want to make an "autonomous car"

Comment: what error are you getting? if it is an error in python what i the traceback message?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen if I use the `var=raw_input(...)` and i enter a single number: 1 i get no error but if i want to make `var = 1` or '1' or "1" i get the following error:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 466, in write
    if not self._isOpen: raise portNotOpenError
ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open

Comment: .... then are you sure the port is open? also you have used python3 tag but raw_input is only in python 2, so which version are you actually using?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes, sorry my version is 2.7.9. I am sure the port is open because if i use the raw_input choice i can communicate with the arduino but by the other hand if I want to send the value of a variable from rasp to arduino to make a switch case in arduino i dont know how to. Thanks for your asnwer

Answer (score 0):

My friends helped me.
The way to send is:

after open the port wait with the time library 1 second.

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

and then the way to send it is:

```
var=b"3"
```

and we send a number 3.
Thanks to everyone.